# Laravel website domain is going to public/publc url

Tags: laravel

Here is my domain http://aambala.de and when i hit url http://aambala.de it goes to this http://aambala.de/public/public
Please anyone can tell me whats the issue?
It was working fine before i tried to enter redirect to this domain from cpanel. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Double check your routes in web.php.

Comment: Thanks mate but that was not the issue, it was issue with domain zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved!
The issue was with Domain Zone as the .de is a special type of domain that requires some more details of your server as static IP to each nameserver your server has. And I had asked the eukhost which was my host to check the configurations of the server and then they had got the domain working.